# Display Description in Nested exp:file:entries Tag

Tags: templates, template-scripting

Here is my template simplified for brevity

```
{exp:structure:entries channel="iconGroup" limit="1" sort="asc" paginate="bottom"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <div class="icon-grid">
    {exp:file:entries directory_id="{file_upload_id}" dynamic="no" disable="categories" orderby="date"}
         <span>{filename}</span>
         <span class="extra-desc">{description}</span>
 {/exp:file:entries}
     </div>
{/exp:structure:entries}
```

The issue i am having is that the description does not show up when it is nested in the entries template. If i move it out of that it shows fine. Is there a way i can make it show up?

Alternatively The main reason i need it nested is to get the file_upload_id from the channel above. Maybe there is a way to get that single entry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never to nest exp:channel:entries, but, in this case, you have a fair reason.

Let's use an embed!

```
{exp:structure:entries channel="iconGroup" limit="1" sort="asc" paginate="bottom" disable="categories|member_data|member_data|pagination"} 
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <div class="icon-grid">
    {embed="includes/.files-and-descriptions" id_of_directory="{file_upload_id}"}
     </div>
{/exp:structure:entries}
```

Then, on embed:

```
{exp:file:entries directory_id="{embed:id_of_directory}" dynamic="no" disable="categories|member_data|member_data|pagination" orderby="date"}
     <span>{filename}</span>
     <span class="extra-desc">{description}</span>
{/exp:file:entries}
```

If this embed is used just once per page, I suggest you to enable the [template cache](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html#template-caching) of both files.